# Sending an email from python django app with azure logic apps

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=bash%2Cclone) tutorial to deploy a basic python django app to azure app service. The full code for the app can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/djangoapp/tree/master/polls). This works fine, its a basic polling app where I can add questions and visitors can answer the poll questions and I can monitor the results.

I then tried to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet) tutorial to create a logic app that will send an email when a poll question is answered. The logic app seems to have been created successfully. At the end of this tutorial there is a short section on integrating this logic app with my django app by adding an HTTP post into the code. However, the section of code it tells me to put it in is in a non python file that doesn't exist in the provided repo. It seems to be some sort of mistake.

So basically I'm not sure where to put the HTTP post in my django app. I've been reading through the django docs to try to better understand what the example app code is doing exactly but I feel like I'm in a bit over my head at this point. The azure tutorials were pretty explicit about what to do at this point.

I realize I posted a lot of content, but if anyone can direct me to where this code is supposed to go in the app, or references for further reading to help me understand this problem better, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: That step in the tutorial doesn't seem right. Please provide [feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=python#feedback) about the document on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues) so the content Team can take a look and fix it.

Comment: Yes it seems that they just reused the text from where to put the HTTP post in the example php app. I have sent feedback. Do you have any idea where I could put this code in the python app?

Comment: I'm checking with the content author about this. Please follow this open GitHub issue for further updates: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55533